# Order by field from other table

Tags: join, laravel, laravel-4, sql-order-by, eloquent

I have 2 tables; `user` and `user_info` with their models `User` and `UserInfo`. `user` holds `id`, `expire` and `user_info_id`, while `user_info` holds `id` and `username`.

I'd like to get all users where `expire` is greater or less than `$now` or `null`, and I'd like to sort the list by `username`. This last part is where my problem lies.

What I currenty have;

```
$usersQ = User::where ('expire', '>', $now)->orWhereNull ('expire');
$usersCount = $usersQ->count ();
$users = $usersQ->get ();
```

I have tried;

```
$usersQ = User::with ('user_info')->join ('user_info', 'user.user_info_id', 'user_info.id')->where ('expire', '>', $now)->orWhereNull ('expire')->orderBy ('username');
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work (SQL syntax error).

Note: I do actually need `User` as my main entity rather than `UserInfo` because I need other information from `User` in my View.

---

## Basically;

```
SELECT user.*, user_info.username, user_info.fname, user_info.lname
FROM user
INNER JOIN user_info ON user.user_info_id = user_info.id
ORDER BY user_info.username ASC;
```

And then I'd be able to get access to everything from `user` and those 3 fields from `user_info`. How on earth do I do that with Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = User::with('user_info')->where('expire', '>', $now)
    ->orWhereNull('expire')->get();
$usercount = $users->count();
```

[Eloquent Relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships)

[Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

Comment: This won't do seeing as Laravel overwrites values of fields with the same name in the original model with the ones in the one that was joined... $user->id would give me `user_info.id` rather than `user.id`. It's the same with other fields.

Comment: Please, add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: robinj that is not true ... then no relationships would ever work since all of them will have primary keys and foreign keys, etc

Comment: @zaq178miami This is eager loading 'user_info' for any user that meets the criteria setup by those wheres.

Comment: you are confusing your joins which you are not doing correctly with how eloquent builds queries for relationships. They are separate things.

Comment: `BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::user_info()`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, damn. Seems I got the order wrong.

```
$usersQ = User::join ('user_info', 'user_info.id', '=', 'user.user_info_id')->orderBy ($order)->where ('expire', '>', $now)->orWhereNull ('expire');
$usersCount = $usersQ->count ();
$users = $usersQ->get ();
```

This is working just fine, except for the bug in Laravel (yes, it's a bug in my opinion) that overwrites the value of any field with a duplicate name. Would be great if anyone knew a fix for that... Joins are pretty much useless if your `id` gets overwritten.

Comment: its not a BUG ... look at the queries generated and you will see what is happening.

Comment: This topic on Laravel's forum [Laravel 4 - Eloquent Alias](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=9884) shows some tricks to deal with column values overwrite. I guess something like that can be achieved for columns via accessors (which may doesn't work for someone).

Comment: It's incredible how a simple task like this seems simply impossible to achieve with Laravel... Either that or nobody else cares to give a decent (*working*) answer.